# Get open ports count in ubuntu distro.

Tags: linux

I'm working in application that monitor the open ports count in Ubuntu distro., my question is how to get the count of open ports for each processe by terminal commands ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `netstat -anltp | grep "LISTEN"` to list all open ports.

Try this for the count: `netstat -anltp | grep "LISTEN" | wc`